# Manga where the main character is reincarnated as a dungeon master and befriends an ancient dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I completely lost the manga and need help finding it.

The main character is reincarnated as a dungeon master (or demon lord; just something along those lines) and he befriends an ancient dragon.

A hero is sent to scout out his dungeon, but the main character sets up ghosts and the hero gets scared of them, which causes her to pass out.

Answer (score 3):

The manga was *[Maou ni Natta node, Dungeon Tsukutte Jingai Musume to Honobono suru](https://anilist.co/manga/106233/Maou-ni-Natta-node-Dungeon-Tsukutte-Jingai-Musume-to-Honobono-suru)*, aka *I Became the Demon Lord so I Created a Dungeon and Spend Heartwarming Time There with Non-Human Girls*

[image: Front cover of Maou ni Natta node, Dungeon Tsukutte Jingai Musume to Honobono suru]

> Before I realized, I had become the guardian of a dungeon, a Demon Lord. I was suddenly in a dangerous world with giant monsters loitering around, fighting for their existence, so I thought to go about developing the dungeon in order to not die but —- for some reason I was having quite the good time... how did it turn out like this?

[Fandom wiki](https://maou-ni-natta-node.fandom.com/wiki/Maou_ni_Natta_node,_Dungeon_Tsukutte_Jingai_Musume_to_Honobono_suru)

Comment: Well, that didn't take long.

Comment: If possible, please come back and accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you won't be able to accept for another 47 hours or so, but we hope you'll stick around. I'm also going to [edit] a bit more detail in so as to help anyone else looking for the manga.